# Shall I refactor code if it hides the flow of the program?

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, code-readability

I have built restful web services. The services endpoints have a similar logic:

If the input validation succeeds, do a database operation and return the result.

If the db operation fails, return the db error.

If the validation fail, return a response with information on the failed validation

My code was explicit in the sense you can read the code and understand the flow of the program.

A coworker refactored it so that this basic flow is refactored in a utility class which main function takes the request body, the db operation and the handlers.

Now the code doesn't express the flow but the basic logic is refactored.

What is the best practice? Would you sacrifice readability for refactoring?

Yes unit test will be reduced a bit too.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest posting the before and after versions at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also review the definition of [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). It doesn't make sense to contrast refactoring with readability. Refactoring is not a feature.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105125/code-readability-vs-refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that the utility class which contains refactored code, will be reusable in many other similar scenarios for operations, for example,

- validating the input,
- running database operation,
- returning the result

If it will be reusable in other similar scenarios, then it is okay to refactor.

I guess it would be better to refactor, as you can see from the point of view of maintanable code, Refactoring servers a better purpose. (If time permits, I guess, you could make the new code readable also, to make the flow explicit.)